# I keep getting this dplyr and loadNamespaceerror message when trying to find the value of $1 invested 5 years ago

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I'm very new to R, I have never used it before nor used any software programs besides Excel. For my class, we have to find 2 stocks and see how much $1 invested into these companies over the past 5 years will have given us returns. I have written the following code that all of the other students in my class have written. They all are able to get the plots and have the code working fine. But for me, I keep getting error messages. Please give advise me on how to fix it, thank you so much!

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("tidyquant")
library("tidyverse")
library("tidyquant")

stock_names <- c("ENPH", "TEAM")
stocks <- tq_get(stock_names, from ='2017-01-01') 
# daily data for the last 5 years

stocks_ret <- stocks %>%
              group_by(symbols) %>%
              tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
                   mutate_fun = periodReturn,
                   period = "daily",
                   col_rename = "ret")

stocks_ret <- stocks_ret %>% mutate(cumret =cumprod(1+ret)) 
 
stocks_ret %>% ggplot(aes(date, cumret, color = symbol)) + 
geom_line() + ggtitle("Value of $1 invested 5 years ago")
```

But I keep getting this error message in the R Console

```
> Error in group_by(., symbols) : object 'stocks' not found
> 
>  stocks_ret <- stocks_ret %>% mutate(cumret =cumprod(1+ret))    Error
> in mutate(., cumret = cumprod(1 + ret)) : 
> 
>   object 'stocks_ret' not found
> 
>  stocks_ret %>% ggplot(aes(date, cumret, color = symbol)) +
> geom_line()+ggtitle("Value of $1 invested 5 years ago")
> 
> Error in ggplot(., aes(date, cumret, color = symbol)) : 
> 
>   object 'stocks_ret' not found
> 
>  library("tidyverse")
>  library("tidyquant")
> 
>  stock_names <- c("ENPH", "TEAM")
> 
>  stocks <- tq_get(stock_names, from ='2017-01-01') # daily data for
> the last 5 years
> 
> Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
> 
>  Problem while computing `data.. = purrr::map(...)`.
> 
> Caused by error in `loadNamespace()`:
> 
>  there is no package called ‘lava’
> 
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Please follow the guideline for indenting the code to make it readable for the audience looking at your question https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: on your `group_by` function call, you should specify `symbol` instead of `symbols` as this is the column name you need. You can see them when you call `names(stocks)`